# CSS Margin-Top on element

Tags: html, css

How do I give **margin-top** on the following spans so they don't stay too close to each other?

```css
.video-tags{
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
  
}
```

```html
<span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span>
<span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `inline-block`

```
.video-tags{
  margin-top: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.video-tags {
    float: left
}
```

... or

```
.video-tags {
    display: inline-block
}
```

Comment: It works, but you didn't actually apply it in your fiddle

Answer (score 1):

Just to explain since no one really did... A span is an inline element.  Inline elements are meant to flow with the content that surrounds them and so they react differently to things such as margin.  In order to be able to put a margin on them, you need to turn them into block elements.  However, you don't want to mess up their positioning by setting them to block so you set them to inline-block so they stay inline, yet gain the form of a block level element.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is increase the separation between line boxes, that is, the [line height](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#line-height).

> As described in the section on [inline formatting contexts](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#inline-formatting), user
>   agents flow inline-level boxes into a vertical stack of [line
>   boxes](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#line-box).

You can set a minimum value using the [`line-height`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-line-height) property.

> On a [block container element](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-boxes) whose content is composed of
>   [inline-level](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#inline-level) elements, `line-height` specifies the *minimal*
>   height of line boxes within the element.

```css
body {
  line-height: 50px;
}
.video-tags {
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span>
<span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span>
```

Alternatively, you can increase the height of the inline-level elements inside the line box. However, the margin box is not always used:

> The height of each inline-level box in the line box is calculated. For
>   replaced elements, inline-block elements, and inline-table elements,
>   this is the height of their margin box; for inline boxes, this is
>   their `line-height`.

That is, for inline boxes like your spans, margins and paddings are ignored when calculating the separation between lines.

However, you could use `line-height`, now on the spans instead of on the container:

> On a non-replaced [inline](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#inline-boxes) element, `line-height` specifies the
>   height that is used in the calculation of the line box height.

```css
.video-tags {
  line-height: 50px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span>
<span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span>
```

Alternatively, display your spans as inline-blocks. Then the height of their whole margin box will be taken into account.

```css
.video-tags {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span>
<span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span><span class="video-tags"><a href='/tag/{{ vTag }}/' title="{{ vTag }} My Video" class='video-tags'>{{ vTag }} &nbsp;</a></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.video-tags{
  margin: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: So just modify block by inline-block